# English and arabic mixed string not ordered correctly Qt

Tags: c++, qt

So I have a code in Qt that goes joins the Strings “john جونسون” and “(جيد جداً), but when i add them up I get the answer in a wrong order ex.:

john (جيد جداً) جونسون’

Comment: How do you "add them up"? Could this be because the arabic is right-to-left?

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Are you sure what qt has done is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Qt. It is a unicode thing. Qt just adds the characters.

The problem arises because the string starts of in LTR(left to right), with 'jhon' because that is in latin alphabet, but then when you add an arabic word to that, the first letter of that word, should be on the right, because arabic is a RTL script. This means that the last letter (represented by the last bytes) is on the left. So the place where the second string got added is - in memory - the end of the string.

You add an Arabic string to the string, because Arabic also uses '(', and thus, you stay in RTL mode.

So you need to explicitly mark the switchover back to LTR:

```
QString ltr{"\u200e"};
QString a {"john جونسون"};
QString b {"(جيد جداً)"};
std::cout << (a+ltr+b).toStdString()<< std::endl;
```

This will add a [Left to right zero width character](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Implicit_Directional_Marks) in between, which tells, whatever is displaying your string, from that point onwards, the end of the string is on the right again. (Until it reaches the arabic characters again.)